# Does GRASS GIS work on latest Macs with M1 chip?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, mac

Does GRASS GIS work on Macs with M1 chip?

Comment: Have you looked for system requirements for each of the software products that you wish to run on your proposed hardware and OS version?

Comment: I've already checked that, no information regarding that is available.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't support the current m1 macs yet.

Comment: Are you talking about the native M1 support? Is it possible to run the software through Rosetta 2 or running Windows on M1 macs?

Comment: Has anyone managed to install QGIS and GRASS GIS on these new Macs? Do they work with Rosetta?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s worked for 7.9 dev.

But never try for current release 8 advanced preview.

Answer (score 0):

The official releases (what version is indifferent, well at least from 7.8.6) will work on Rosetta 2. No problem.
Soon to be released, official distributions will be build natively for any architecture. For the very eager contestant, build easily for your self with script from https://github.com/nilason/grass-conda.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, new Mac binaries supporting Apple ARM processors (M1 and M2 currently) for GRASS 8.3 and 8.2.1 have become available at http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads.

In addition, also a new Intel binary for GRASS 8.3. Intel binaries also work on Apple ARM processor Macs using its "Rosetta" emulation engine.

Source: https://twitter.com/GRASSGIS/status/1643197971650031619